# Java NIO. Why flip() method breaks my program?

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer, socketchannel

Java code below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        SocketChannel c = SocketChannel.open();
        c.connect(new InetSocketAddress("google.com", 80));

        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        b.put("Request".getBytes());

        System.out.println("Write: " + c.write(b));

        int i;
        while ((i = c.read(b)) != -1) {

            System.out.println("Read: " + i);
            b.clear();

        }
    }
}
```

Actual Result:

> Write: 1017 Read: 0 Read: 1024 Read: 44

First time, method `read()` read 0 bytes. It is not cool.

I modified my code:

```
    b.put("Request".getBytes());

    System.out.println("Write: " + c.write(b));

    b.flip(); //I added this line
    int i;
    while ((i = c.read(b)) != -1) {

        System.out.println("Read: " + i);
        b.clear();

    }
```

Actual results:

> Write: 1017 Read: 1024 Read: 44

It already looks better. Thanks `flip()` for this!

Next, I put to buffer String **"Request"**, this String has length **7**, but method `write()`returned **1017**.

What information method wrote to channel?

I am not sure, that method wrote string **"Request"**.

Ok, I modified my code again:

```
    b.put("Request".getBytes());

    b.flip(); // I added this line
    System.out.println("Write: " + c.write(b));

    b.flip();
    int i;
    while ((i = c.read(b)) != -1) {

        System.out.println("Read: " + i);
        b.clear();

    }
```

Actual results:

> Write: 7

and code crashed...

**By why? Where is my mistake?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `flip` method needs to be called **before** reading data from the buffer. The `flip()` method, reset the buffer's `limit` to the current position  and reset the buffer's `position` to 0.

So, if you have 7 byte of data in `ByteBuffer`, your position (starting from 0), would be 7. `flip()`'ing it, would make `limit = 7`, `position = 0`. Now, reading can occur.

Here's an example on how to best use `flip()`:

```
public static final void nioCopy(ReadableByteChannel input, WritableByteChannel output) throws IOException {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    while (input.read(buffer) != -1) {
        //Flip buffer
        buffer.flip();
        //Write to destination
        output.write(buffer);
        //Compact
        buffer.compact();
    }

    //In case we have remainder
    buffer.flip();
    while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
        //Write to output
        output.write(buffer);
    }
}
```

- [Additional resource](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1438/java-working-with-buffers/).

Answer (score 3):

Despite its (poorly chosen) name, `flip()` is not symmetric. You must call it before any operation that gets from the buffer (write or get), and call either `compact()` or `clear()` afterwards to put the buffer back into a state where it is ready for reading or putting.